# Dataset where a group is offered a privilege?

Tags: reference-request, data-request, adverse-selection, selection-bias

I am trying to find a dataset where a population is put through a selection process, after the selection process a treatment is applied, and we know the covariates of the whole population, but perhaps only the response variables of the treated members.

A canonical example might be data on college admissions, where we have data on the entire pool of the applicants (both accepted and rejected), but then outcome data only on the accepted students.